# CSS Media Queries n00b, How to Specify Element Height Properly?

Tags: iphone, css, mobile, media-queries

First, I apologize for the enormous pictures.

I'm new to media queries. Here's how my site looks when I test in my browser and set the window width to 320px:

[image: How It's Supposed to Look]

That is how I want my site to appear on mobile phones. But when I load it on my iPhone, it appears like this:
[image: How It Actually Looks]

Here is the query I am using:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) 
    and (max-device-width : 480px), 
    screen and (max-width : 850px) {
```

Obviously, this is because the width of the iphone is much greater than 320px. How do I make my site look like the first image, when the device has the resolution of the second image?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the iPhone 5. I don't have a lot of experience with this, but based on what I am reading at http://www.stephentgilbert.com/mediaqueries/#iPhone, I would try changing max-device-width to 568px. I believe it is also retina, so you might also need `and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)` in there as well.

Comment: My media query is working properly I think, because the white 'more' arrow is appearing, which it only does inside the query.

I think I'm going to have to write some javascript to make the heights of all the page elements based on a percentage of the window width...

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like it might be a viewport issue?

Try putting:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

into the head of your html.